# user table on admin page, takes to long to load

Tags: php, mysql

I use this query:

```
$result_members = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members");
```

The results are displayed in a table on my admin page like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_members))
{
$id = $row['id'];
$firstname = $row['firstname'];
...

<tr>
 <td><? echo "$id"; ?></td>
 <td><? echo "$firstname"; ?></td>
 ...
</tr>
}
```

I use jQuery pagination which displays 50 rows per page, and jquery Autocomplete to search in table.

Both loading and search takes alot of time. From several seconds up to a minute. I have about 5.000 members in my db.

I reckon there's a better way to do this. I'm not experienced in mysql, so if you could show me a simple way to make this work smoothly, I'd be really happy! :)

Regards

Virik

Comment: I am not sure how much faster it will be but it is better to grab the fields you only need, versus the *kind of lazy* catch all (*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be not only database related slowdown. It can be also caused by your computer processing HTML at first, then jQuery pagination. Anyway, it is not a good idea to query 5000 rows and display them on the same page, although they are paginated.

Maybe you would be interested in flexigrid.info -  a nice javascript solution that displays data from your database. It not only loads data as you need it, but also allows sorting and some manipulations(row adding and deleting).

Comment: Spent hours customizing it, and it works really great on all my tables. Except for the loading issue on the members table. Should I use ajax, json or something like that ?

Comment: Virik, Flexigrid is much more powerful than the tool you are using. One of the main disadvantages is that it can't load content dynamically, which means it has to load all 5K rows (and probably you will not even go to 2nd page). Flexigrid (or any other similar tool that can use ajax) will load only those rows that you want to be displayed on this particular page. I doubt that you will solve your issues using the tool you are using at the moment.

Comment: Thank you Tim, I'll check it out.

Looks like I have a few hours of customizing waiting for me ;)

Comment: Don't forget to save your source code when you're done. You may always reuse it for future projects if using Flexigrid ;) And have a look at one of the examples (https://github.com/paulopmx/Flexigrid/blob/master/demo/post-json.php). It will same you a LOT of time.

Comment: You need to set your members.php to return json based on GET variables that Flexigrid sends. Without seeing your code I can't help you.

Comment: You need to retrieve `$page` and `$rp` variables from POSTed data. You also need to query DB using all those variables, not only `LIMIT` (line 42).

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
SELECT * FROM members
```

to

```
SELECT * FROM members LIMIT 200
```

Downside is, that will only let you show/search the first 4 pages of users. If you want to get around that, you need to have the jQuery page dynamically request more data, which makes things an order of magnitude more complicated.

### How to add this functionality

A lot of this code depends on what pagination plugins you're using. Some plugins have [integrated support for it](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination), others you might have to hack in.

However, one thing that doesn't really change is the server side stuff. You need a second PHP script that just returns a page of results given. Here's one.

`fetch_page.php`:

```
<?
define('RESULTS_PER_PAGE', 50);
$page = $_GET['page];
$page = (int) $page; // Cast to int to prevent sql injections and let us do math on it.

$start = $page * RESULTS_PER_PAGE;
$end = ($page + 1) * RESULTS_PER PAGE;

$result_members = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members LIMIT $start, $end");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_members))
{
$id = $row['id'];
$firstname = $row['firstname'];
...

<tr>
 <td><? echo "$id"; ?></td>
 <td><? echo "$firstname"; ?></td>
 ...
</tr>
}
?>
```

Note that doing search on this is an entirely different matter. There are two ways of doing seach:

1) Load all the data from the server onto the client. This is pretty slow, especially since javascript/DOM isn't really the right way to store/search a lot of data. However, it's easy to put together.

2) Do the search on the database server and return the result to the client. This is also pretty complicated.

You should consider whether this added complexity is justified. Why do you need to search through your user table?

Comment: I have to be able to manage all users from the admin page, not just 200.

Comment: Here's a screen of the table:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ve20u9qzelarzza/screen.jpg

jQuery page dynamically request more data sounds like what I need. Where do I begin? I want to make this as simple as possible, without using complex plugins :)

Comment: What jQuery plugin are you using to paginate? I can give you some general purpose directions without that, but I can give more specific/useful advice if I know that.

Comment: @Ryan B, he has other fields in the query, he just truncated the code. Also, not retrieving some of the fields isn't much of a performance boost.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at MySQL's `LIMIT` clause. What you want to do is only select the 50 rows you want using that.

Comment: I have to be able to manage all users from the admin page, not just 50.

Comment: But you're only showing 50 at any time. So you would need to use Ajax to load the results you need like @Nick ODell said. It wouldn't be a "simple" change though.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for.. how do I do that :)